# Importing Eclipse project with 2 libraries to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I am trying to import my Eclipse project into Android Studio.  My project in Eclipse has 2 libraries -- my main library with all my code (BibleTriviaLite) and a SDK library that I downloaded to reference as a library (SwarmConnect).  See screenshot below.

[image: eclipse project structure]

I followed all the steps in the Migrating from Eclipse document.  I am now at this point:

[image]

I select OK and then OK.  Then I get this popup:

[image]

Not sure what to do at this point.  I cannot find any documentation that will help me with this specific migration.  Is Android Studio just not developed enough to accomplish this type of import yet or am I just missing something?

**EDIT 1**

- I tried setting the path of JAVA_HOME to:  C:\Users\lyonsmg\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk
- I tried creating a `local.properties` file in the root of the project `BibleTriviaLite` and adding this single line in the file:  `sdk.dir=C:\Users\lyonsmg\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk`.

Both attempts above give the same error when I try to import the `build.gradle` file.

**EDIT 2**

- I tried in my "paths" doing my slashes like `\`, `\\` and `/`.  A lot of different SO links say to do it all different ways but they all gave the same error.

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: I am using Android Studio 0.2.6, Build 130.795391.

Comment: @Matt i am getting same issue if found solution then put answer.

Comment: @Harshid I never found solution.  I just am staying with Eclipse for now.

Answer (score 0):

Create an ANDROID_HOME environmental variable pointing to the Android sdk directory which is included in Android Studio or create a local.properties file containing the path to the Android sdk for each of your projects. The local.properties file should be located in the root / workspace directory of your project; it needs only to contain one line:
sdk.dir=C:/android-studio/sdk

Comment: I just tried each solution one at a time and both gave me the same error as before when trying to import the build.gradle file.  The path I tried for JAVA_HOME was `C:\Users\lyonsmg\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk` and the line I used in `local.properties` was `sdk.dir=C:\Users\lyonsmg\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk`.  Does it look like I missed a step somewhere?

Comment: Check my EDIT to my opening post.

Comment: As a side note, when I imported from one Android studio to a different one I used settings.gradle and not build.gradle.